# Sending HTML e-mails from PHP

Tags: php, forms, email, sendmail, html-email

MYSqL works fine but I do not get emails why?

```
<?php
    //include the connection file

    require_once('connection.php');

    //save the data on the DB and send the email

        if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'submitform')
        {
        //recieve the variables

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $url = $_POST['url'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $ip = gethostbyname($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        //save the data on the DB

        mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);

        $insert_query = sprintf("INSERT INTO contacts (name, email, url, comment, date, ip) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, NOW(), %s)",
                            sanitize($name, "text"),
                            sanitize($email, "text"),
                            sanitize($url, "text"),
                            sanitize($comment, "text"),
                            sanitize($ip, "text"));

        $result = mysql_query($insert_query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

        if($result)
        {
            //send the email

            $to = "email@aol.com";
            $subject = "message from website";

            //headers and subject
            $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
            $headers .= "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n";

            $body = "New contact<br />";
            $body .= "Name: ".$name."<br />";
            $body .= "Email: ".$email."<br />";
            $body .= "Comment: ".$comment."<br />";
            $body .= "IP: ".$ip."<br />";

            mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

            //ok message

            echo "Your message has been sent";
        }
        }

        function sanitize($value, $type) 
        {
        $value = (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? addslashes($value) : $value;

        switch ($type) {
        case "text":
          $value = ($value != "") ? "'" . $value . "'" : "NULL";
          break;    
        case "long":
        case "int":
          $value = ($value != "") ? intval($value) : "NULL";
          break;
        case "double":
          $value = ($value != "") ? "'" . doubleval($value) . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        case "date":
          $value = ($value != "") ? "'" . $value . "'" : "NULL";
          break;
        }

        return $value;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can we have the part of your code that creates the $to, $subject, $headers variables?

Comment: Are you running this on your local server? If yes then you need to have a mail (I.e. sendmail) server configured on it.

Comment: You need to post relevant code in your questions.  Otherwise, we can't help.  :/

Answer (score 5):

Sending e-mails from servers can be tricky when the e-mails suddenly stop. You'll want to definitely implement some sort of logging in the event a failure occurs. In regard to your particular issue this could be a variety of things. `MySQL` is unrelated to `mail()` and so one working has no direct effect on the other unless you have code that dictates such an interaction. This is a fairly technical explanation.

1. The e-mail address that you originally posted was for `aol.com`. If that's the case, then you'll want to check out the [AOL sender policies](http://postmaster.aol.com/). They may be doing a [reverse look-up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) and not finding your server's name in the [MX record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) reverse look-up for [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System). Additionally they like things like [SPF records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPF_record), [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DKIM), and [Domain-Keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_keys).
2. You will not receive the email if the [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Address) for your web server or the block of IPs registered by your web host are on a blocklist (shared hosting tends to have more than one website sending e-mails). There are several sites that allow you to check if your `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` is on a blocklist. For example you might try: http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check
3. Since you're sending to AOL you are trying to send a MIME HTML-only e-mail that begins without an HTML tag. (You might try plain text.)
4. Additionally since you're sending an e-mail to AOL (to your own address) you may more than likely be testing with your own address, and if that's the case AOL has the tendency to block e-mails to them, from their e-mail domain, but not sent by them. This may seem like relaying or a spoof attempt.
5. If you're on a local network most ISPs typically block port 25 to prevent the spread of worms and viruses from infected computers hosted on their networks.
6. If your sendmail client isn't installed or configured in your PHP installation this might be the case. Check `phpinfo()` to see if it's installed.
7. Your server may be running a firewall like IP Tables that could have outbound broadcasts from port 25 blocked.(Not likely, but a possible.)
8. If [Sendmail](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php) is configured properly, you can update the config file by specifying a log for logging all `mail()` transactions. This will tell you if the e-mail is being bounced and any response during the handshakes between the server.

Comment: wow, you type fast and or have to much free time on your hands :-)